# Easy way to implement Date/Time picker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone know what the easiest way to implement a date/time picker in bootstrap/razor html code is? I currently have the program running fine by entering directly as:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
    </div>
```

But would love a date/time picker to popup when date is selected? Any suggestions?

Simplicity is key here as the code is for some basic students to see.

EDITED but not working:

My new head, still not working:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>App Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#date").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: See my updated post, the javascript and jQuery code needs to go in your <head> section.

Comment: Alas still not working, have moved it my head (as above). Any ideas?

Comment: You are using an older version of jQuery and you aren't including jquery ui. Copy and paste from my code and get rid of your jquery reference. Also be sure to add the jquery-ui.css reference too.

Comment: Thanks. I will do. Can I use the JQuery CSS reference even though I am using Bootstrap CSS

Comment: yes, the jquery ui css is only for the jquery ui components (calendar).

Comment: Wonderful. works perfectly. Thanks for all your consistent help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Datepicker

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
```

**Update:**

The `#date` refers to the name in your model. If you need to add other datepickers, just make sure to change `#date` to the new property name

Comment: Ive never used JQuery before, is it as simple as adding it to the HTML? Or does it need plugins etc installed?

Comment: Take a look around on the site. You will need to add a reference to jquery and jquery ui in your HTML. www.jquery.com will have some tutorials as well.

Comment: Thanks Rob, also quickly followed the tutorials and have edited my code as in my edited post however still doesnt seem to work? Does it mabe not work with Razor?

Comment: Try the updated code, it should work. make sure the code goes in your <head> section. If you razor view uses a layout or master page it might need to go in your @section head { } area

Answer (score 0):

I use Calendar control from AjaxControlToolkit library and is very good. You have every thing how to implement it in this link:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With MVC you may want to checkout the following post. 
All the date or date/time fields just work regardless of thier field name in your model.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx